# Short story about a man inadvertently winnng a road rage battle

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

So years ago I read a story that was more or less this: a man driving with his family gets cut off and gets into it with the driver of the other car, they battle aggressively, he ends up besting the other guy. He thinks this is just a normal occurrence but when it ends he gets a message saying congratulations, you are the new champion, challenger number 1 is so and so... I read this in a collection probably in the early 70s. Anybody know it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you all! The Ellison story is the one